# Get the value of a javascript variable with java

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I have a webpage with a declared variable

```
var JAVA_SCRIPT_VARIABLE = { some : "funny json"}
```

which I want to read in a String.

1. Attempt ui4j ( https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j ).

   ```
   Object result = page.executeScript("JAVA_SCRIPT_VARIABLE");
   ```

did not work out. I could not see anything in the debugger.

2. Attempt HTMLUnit

   ```
   ScriptResult scriptResult = page.executeJavaScript("JAVA_SCRIPT_VARIABLE");
   Object javaScriptResult = scriptResult.getJavaScriptResult();
   ```

Now I can see, that the json is read and available in a sort of map of the object type **net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeObject** . Is there a possibilty to get the exact JSON-String out of this NativeObject?

Has someone an idea what did I do wrong in either attempt 1 or 2 ? Or have someone an idea, which else I could try ? (Apart from parsing the whole HTML-Page with Jsoup and then use a regular expression)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the Json value with Ui4j.

Here is sample for your case.

```
JSObject variable = (JSObject) page.executeScript("JAVA_SCRIPT_VARIABLE");
System.out.println(variable.getMember("some"));
```

Do not forget to import JSObject from **netscape.javascript.JSObject**